# Unable to export cloud sql database

Tags: google-cloud-sql

In cloud SQL, I am getting an error on exporting one particular Postgres database using SQL type export.
The error I see in the notification is "Unknown error."
If I retry from notification it shows "The server has encountered a problem. Please try again."
How to fix this?

[image]

Notification on failure: 
[image]

On Clicking Retry:
[image]

log:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

More information about an export operations can be gathered by checking the status of the export ([here is how](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/checking-status-import-export)), and looking into the operations logs ([here is how](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/instance-info#logs)). If the logs do not reveal insights to help fix the issue, then more details should be shared as to how the export operation is performed by looking at the different methods ([explained here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting)). Be as explicit as possible, and please share the expanded logs while obfuscating private information.

Comment: Thanks I've checked the links you provided and following the same..
I've attached screenshots. I am not seeing any logs related to this in log viewer.

Comment: added log screenshot as well.

Comment: Could you verify if the object created by the export was actually successfully created in the bucket specified despite what the console notifications indicate? If the object exists, can you check if the export file associated with the object is complete and well-formed?

Also, could you try the export operation via the gcloud command which is specified in the “gcloud” tab from this page https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/exporting.

Comment: If this is still unsuccessful, please try to perform a pg_dump, as documented here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html. This procedure will necessitate your Cloud SQL instance to accept connection from the machine performing this, and the guidelines to do so are detailed here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP.

Finally, could you confirm if the “connection to client lost” alert log’s timestamp coincides with the time at which the export operation was initiated?

Comment: There is nothing being created in bucket.
I tried creating export via gcloud command but error is same.
And yes “connection to client lost" is coming when we do export.
I tried your another suggestion which is using pg_dump and it works!
For now I am able to export and trying to import the same in another instance.
Thanks a lot for your support and guidance. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same issue recently (including the same "connection to client lost" in the logs). When searching noticed that there was maintenance pending on the sql instance. After scheduling the maintenance and rebooting the instance, exporting worked once again.